# Sharepoint 2013 Page Workflow getting cancelled

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have a 3-stage approval workflow setup for pages on a SharePoint site and it keeps failing (cancelling) after the 1st stage.

Here's what's happening in the first stage:

**Stage: Contributor Review**

> Set Workflow Status to Pending KCSII Review
>
> then Set Approval Status to Not Confirmed
>
> > **App Step**
> >
> > > Assign a task to KCSII (Task outcome to Variable: KCSII Approval | Task ID to Variable: TaskID
> >
> > **Transition to stage**
> >
> > > If Variable: KCSII Approval equals Rejected
> > >
> > > > Go to Rejected
> > >
> > > Else
> > >
> > > > Go to Publisher Review

The task is successfully created & assigned to KCSII (a SharePoint group) but when the person goes in and approves or rejects the item, the workflow goes into "Activity in progress" status with the following details:

> *Activity in progress. Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP InternalServerError to http:// [our domain]/kb/01/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'4aa16afe-d068-4847-a0fd-31a8558398d2')/Items(67) Correlation Id: 538af876-18c7-49ad-a850-d028bac129fe Instance Id: 6c88b440-9a53-4ecd-b873-5e2a1c420055 *

THEN after about a minute, lists the 'Status' as the 2nd stage and goes into "Cancelled" Internal Status with the following details (the 2nd stage is never started):

> *RequestorId: c17f35ee-9fb6-af74-473c-3cd45a32a58d. Details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["111"],"SPRequestGuid":["72ac68f5-84a9-46c6-bb23-5adaa2590338"],"request-id":["72ac68f5-84a9-46c6-bb23-5adaa2590338"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4569"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Mon, 05 Jan 2015 21:51:34 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)*

Here's what I've tried:

- I've tried this exact workflow on a document library and it works perfectly.
- I tried this workflow on pages for another site & got the same failure
- I've tried it with & without using an 'app step' but get the same results
- I've tired rebuilding this workflow multiple ways (even stripping it down to just the basic task) but get the same failure
- I've tried disabling the workflow feature for the site, deleting all workflows, then enabling the feature & rebuilding the workflows (same result)

I *think* this is an issue with the outcome of the task being assigned to the variable (maybe a permissions issue?) but I'm not sure... How do I track down this issue? Does that message make sense to any of you?

I greatly appreciate any help that can be offered (I've been fighting this for a month now!)

Thank You! 
Kyle

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what the problem was: I needed to check out the item in the workflow before editing/updating it. Alternatively, I could disable the required Check In/Check Out feature (tested both and they worked).